# Tried to fix unconfirmed transactions, remaining balance gone!

Tags: multibit, unconfirmed-transactions

apologies if some of the details aren't relevant, I'm not quite sure what's going on and I'm getting desperate!

I'm using the latest version of MultiBit HD. 2 days ago I bought some BTC (I already had a little in my wallet) and tried to make 3 payments. They appeared at blockchain.info pretty quickly, and I could see in MultiBit that they had been seen by peers, but remained unconfirmed. The transaction fee for each was set to the default (0.0001 BTC), making the fee-per-byte 19.231 sat/B for one transaction and 44.444 for the other two.

As I couldn't work out why it was taking so long I tried to cancel the transactions, so that I could resend with a higher fee, but the option to reset the blockchain & transactions (as per the MultiBit manual) doesn't seem to exist in the current version. Restarting MultiBit did nothing, neither did reinstalling.

I then tried "repair wallet", hoping that this would have the same effect - instead, my remaining balance disappeared! A small amount of BTC has appeared as unconfirmed though - has my balance just somehow become unconfirmed? Why/how do I avoid this in future? And, what should I do about the outstanding transactions? The intended recipients are starting to get annoyed with me, and I can't just buy more BTC and send that with a higher fee in case the old transactions suddenly decide to work!

Any help would be extremely gratefully received - even if it's just to tell me how not to make the same mistake again! Transaction ids:

d86bc86b30495d4150a0fb1733038cb0c3fced57803de0e91ad4c13326b28d58
2a8191e9ab4f3d96cdf5a557146d470a0c78a4c7b1b64051c0f90417407019a3
b854be622f4e4fa7229c14b2054b62e4ddd4441e993085fe9f229798e7215f16

TIA :)

Comment: Follow up: my balance is back, leaving this as yet another "unconfirmed transaction" question... I've tried everything in the other answers though (can't double spend - dug out my old PC to fire up a second copy of MultiBit, and it's showing the same exact stuff as the primary copy). Might just have to double pay & write this off as a loss...